# Simulate packet loss in C program language

Tags: c, udp

I have udp server/client code written in C and I want to simulate packet loss because packet loss over my wireless network is too high and I can not perform my tests so I switched to ethernet. For example I want to have 20 % packet loss, how can I do that in C ?

Thx

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code, but you could, for instance, alter a function which recieves packets. And just ignore a packet if `rand() % 100 > 80`.

Comment: @FreeNickname: That's 19% btw. Anyway, `rand()` is probably bad enough it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Yes, I know) And I know that `rand()`'s randomness quality is bad, but I think it doesn't really matter. I just think it's not that important in this case. Still, I'm agree, `>= 80` is more accurate :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you want to simulate network interuptions in your application, as the test would only show that the simulation works. You have to simulate the loss of packets outside of your application.

You can add iptables rules doing that :

```
# for randomly dropping 20% of incoming packets:
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.2 -j DROP

# and for dropping 20% of outgoing packets:
iptables -A OUTPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.2 -j DROP
```

http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/03/11/simulating-dropped-packets-aka-crappy-internets-with-iptables/

Comment: It is UDP, so inside the app is ok.